# Mode of a dataset having distinct numbers

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I am actually a bit confused... about the definition of a *mode*.

> According to the definition I read, it came to my notice that *the number with highest frequency has to be a mode for a given data set*, but then what if I have all the numbers as distinct... In that scenario we won't have a particular number having a frequency more than other elements in the data set...
>   Now if I consider a case when we have **2** numbers in a dataset with same max number of occurrences like:
>   $$2,3,4,5,3,2$$
>   Here **2, 3** both happen to have same maximum frequency and thus we say there are **2** modes...
>   The above is stated similar in case we have **3** modes or **multi** modes ...
>   So if there are all distinct numbers then we would have each number having the same maximum frequency as **1** ..so we can say ***all the numbers are modes***...for that dataset...But then I have seen on some websites claiming that such data sets have  **"NO MODE".**

So again my thought process is contradicting...what claims I am seeing on websites...
So plz some one help me get this basic concept resolved ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have three cases: unimodal, multimodal and no mode

*$\underline{\textrm{unimodal}}$*: A statistical distribution of values with one peak.

Example: $5667$. The mode is obviously $6$.

*$\underline{\textrm{multimodal}}$*: A statistical distribution of values with multiple peaks.

Example: $55677$. The frequencies of 5 and 7 are 2. And we have a lower frequency of 6, which is 1.  Thus the modes are $5$ and $7$.

*$\underline{\textrm{no mode}}$*: A statistical distribution of values with no peaks. All values have the same frequency.

Example: $556677$

Comment: Oh...that peak based definition seems more obvious and digestible...okay that means we don't have any modes in the case of elements with all values occurring equal number of times...

Comment: That´s correct.